# Why is the exponential function not in the subspace of all polynomials?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, polynomials, vector-spaces

The exponential function can be written as

$$e^x = 1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^3}{3!} + \dots.$$

The subspace of all polynomials is $$\text{span}\{1, x,x^2, \dots \}$$

Sure $e^x$ is in this set?

Comment: Any function in the subspace must be a linear combination of a _finite_ number of basis elements.

Comment: What Parcly wrote, and adding: what is true is that $\;e^x\;$ is in the closure  (with respect to uniform convergence) of the span of the polynomials (in fact, **any** continuous function in a closed bounded interval) is. This is the famous Weierstrass approximation theorem.

Comment: @DonAntonio The restriction of $e^x$ to a closed bounded interval is in the closure of $\mathbb{R}[x]$, but not $e^x$ itself. An experienced reader can deduce that from your comment in parentheses, but I'm not sure a beginner would get the correct idea from your comment.

Comment: With your definition, for any $n$, i'ts not hard to deduce $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty }{e^x\over x^n}=\infty$. This is not true for any given  polynomial.

Comment: Similarly, $\sqrt2 = 1 + 1/(2 + 1/(2 + 1/(2 +\cdots$, but we don't expect to find $\sqrt2$ in the rationals.

Comment: Once again we see one of my favourite fallacies of mathematical reasoning: that the limit of an infinite sequence of things that all have a particular property must also have that property.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The function $e^x$ is not in $\text{span}\{1, x,x^2, \dots \}$ because it is no finite linear combination of basis elements (but a countable one). What is true is that $$e^x \in \overline{\text{span}\{1, x,x^2, \dots \}}$$ is in the closure because you can find a sequence in $\text{span}\{1, x,x^2, \dots \}$ which converges to $e^x$. I hope it helps you :)

Comment: What you mention about the closure is a bit unclear. You need to put a topology on the space of continuous functions to even speak about "closure" and "convergence". For example the restriction of $\exp$ to $[0,1]$ is in the closure of $\mathbb{R}[x]$ for the uniform convergence topology, as also mentioned by DonAntonio, but you really have to restrict. If you want you can also say that the sequence of polynomials converges pointwise, but that's not quite satisfactory either.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi You are right. Thanks for pointing that out, I just tried to keep it brief. The closure I meant is respecting the space $(C(K), \Vert \cdot \Vert_\infty)$ for some compact $K \subset \mathbb R$ and that works just fine!

Comment: or closure in formal power series ... :)

Comment: Anyway, " it is no finite linear combination of basis elements" is a rewording of the statement, not a *proof* of it.

Comment: @AnneBauval Awkward to answer a comment of a 7 year old question. Anywas, this question was about why $\mathrm e^x$ is not contained in the span of the monomials and that was just an explanation. I never claimed that my explanation was a proof, to begin with. Reading competence is also a valuable skill.

Answer (score 28):

If $p$ is a polynomial of degree $n$, then the $n$th derivative of $p$ is constant.  Note that the $n$th derivative of $e^x$ is $e^x$.  Now all you have to do is prove that $e^x$ is not constant.

Comment: I find it more natural to consider the $n+1$st, not only but also for avoiding to consider "the $0$th derivative" which might confuse somebody.

Comment: I think this is what the OP wanted, whereas the accepted answer, albeit true, doesn't really address the reason why $e^x$ isn't a polynomial.

Comment: @Vim if you consider what a finite linear combination of the basis vectors looks like, then this answer is equivalent to the accepted one.

Comment: (+1) In the same vein: the only polynomial equal to its own derivative is 0. Honestly, I don't think "this answer is equivalent to the accepted one". Realizing this doesn't require much "reading competence". (+ linear combinations are " finite" by definition)

Answer (score 8):

$\mathrm{span}(A)$ is the set of **finite** linear combinations of terms from $A$. Infinite sums require notions of limits and bring up issues of convergence radii (there are plenty of infinite polynomial that converge only at a single point).