# Does $e^t$ belong to the $\operatorname{span}\{1,t,t^2,\ldots\}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> We know that
> $$
> e^t = 1 + t + \frac{1}{2!} t^2 + \cdots
> $$
> for each $t \in \mathbb{R}$. Does it imply that $e^t \in \text{span}\{1,t,t^2,\cdots\}$?
>
> **Answer:** No.

As $e^t$ can be expanded to form a polynomial it is only natural to think that $e^t$ belongs to the $\operatorname{span}\{1,t,t^2,\ldots\}$. Why is this thought process wrong?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: No it does not, it may be expressed as an infinite polynomial but not a finite one(if you differentiate enough times a finite polynomial has $0$ derivative)

Comment: Key: the exponential function $t\mapsto e^t$ can not be written as a *finite* linear combination of the polynomial functions $t \mapsto t^k$.

Comment: Thanks @everyone

Comment: " e^t can be expanded *to form a polynomial* " is false. Mind the dots in the expansion you are given.

Comment: Look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4038687/base-of-vector-space-ca-b-f/4038695#4038695). Also, $e^t$ can not be expanded as a polynomial. Polynomials are finite (!) sums of monomials. $e^t$ is not.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is the exponential function not in the subspace of all polynomials?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1956433/why-is-the-exponential-function-not-in-the-subspace-of-all-polynomials)

Answer (score 3):

As has been *stated* but not *proved* by several users the function $e^t$ is not a polynomial.
But why is that?
**Answer:** Because for a non-zero polynomial $P(t)$ we have  $\frac {d}{dt}P(t)\neq P(t)$, whereas $ \frac{d}{dt}e^t=e^t$.

Comment: Yes, or "because" the exponential function increases much more rapidly to infinity than any polynomial. Anyway, the question is a duplicate.